# ¿Como guardar un archivo de texto en carpeta interna publica Download?

Tags: android

que tal, tengo una app que genera un archivo de texto, pero lo guarda en el directorio de la app, y necesito guardarlo en la carpeta publica "Download" de la misma memoria interna de mi tableta (NO tarjeta SD), podrían ayudarme por favor, llevo varios días buscando y nada, se los agradecería.

Comment: Que has intentado, agrega tu código es importante. Revisa [ask].

Comment: Hola, mira este el codigo que uso para generar el archivo de texto, por ahora es bastante simple, porque primero queria probar que pudiera guardarlo y efectivamente se guarda, pero se guarda en la carpeta files de la app donde no podemos acceder, y lo que necesito es que se guarde en la carpeta Download de la tableta ya que posteriormente ese archivo se va a extraer y a procesar por una aplicacion de pc, el problema es que como es una app de mi empresa, cuando la app salga a produccion la tabeta no va a tener memoria extrena ni conexion a WIFi, ni nada, la extraccion sera por cable usb.

Comment: String fileName = "333_inv.txt";

                            try {
                                OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName, act_escaneo.MODE_PRIVATE));
                                archivo.write("prueba de almacenamiento");
                                archivo.flush();
                                archivo.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

Comment: es por eso que necesito guardar el archivo en una carpeta publica donde al conectar la tableta por usb, desde la pc se pueda extraer sin problema, espero puedas ayudarme y gracias.